# Any suggestion for mobile datepicker

Tags: javascript, mobile, datepicker

I'm building mobile widget based on javascript and html for which I need a calendar module build on javascript. I tried UI datepicker but its quite slow when runs on phone. any suggestion is going to help me alot.

Comment: are there any specific devices that you're targeting or mobile web in general?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using jQuery, you can try [Mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com), a customizable datepicker optimized for touch devices

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it will meet your needs, but try the [Any+Time™ DatePicker/TimePicker AJAX Calendar Widget](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/)!

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote one in the hopes that someone could expand on it....http://toddmhorst.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this date picker, it works on android and iOs devices: http://tech.cibul.net/cibulcalendar-a-date-range-picker/