# jQuery - Mobile date picker control

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, datepicker

Is there a Date Picker control that I could use on jQuery Mobile?

It needs to be able to save dates locally, etc.

Comment: The unfortunate think about the experimental calendar is they are refactoring it, so it the changes could be significant.

Comment: I am rather confused. I found this question looking for a **calendar** (to show events by week, day, time, etc..) not a date-picker: The answers, including the accepted one provide, provide date-pickers, though. But the "Needs to be able to save dates locally etc." requirement indicates an actual calendar, not just a date picker, so what's going on here?!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's one that has some good capabilities:

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/

Comment: I'm using this one and it works great. Had some issues with the one on the JQM site: http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/ui-datepicker/

Comment: The only thing I did not like about this calendar is that forcing mm/dd/yyyy date format broke it..

Answer (score 3):

There is an experimental calendar. I used it successfully.

Take a look here:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/ui-datepicker/

Comment: Very Intesting ... Any ideas how/if I would be able to create note on dates and save them?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to create notes on dates. If it tells you what was clicked - where's the problem?

Comment: Link is now broken, new link ( on github ) is https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Mobile-Themed-DatePicker

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap) application and where I need datepicker/calender capabilities:

Basically on your page you add algon with CSS and JavaScript code for [jQuery Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_Mobile):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.css" />

<div data-role="content">
    <input name="myminutesdate" id="myminutesdate" type="date" data-role="datebox"
           data-options='{"mode": "calbox","dateFormat":"%m/%d/%Y","calUsePickers": true, "calNoHeader": true,"highDates": ["2012-12-07" , "2012-07-12"] }' ></input>
```

Most importantly:

```
$("#minutesPage").live('pageshow',function(event) {
    var today = new Date();

    var date = today.getDate();
    var month = (today.getMonth()+1);
    var year = today.getFullYear();

    var todayStr = month+"/"+date+"/"+year;
    $('#myminutesdate').trigger('datebox', {'method':'set', 'value':todayStr});
});
```

Also, if you don't want a popup, you can make it static.

Answer (score 0):

For a calendar view take a look at the [Calendar Control](http://blog.mobiscroll.com/introducing-the-mobiscroll-calendar/)

It works with or without date and time spinners (calendar only is possible). It also integrates with jQuery Mobile Themes, if you're looking for that.

Answer (score 0):

While I was searching for a date picker to use on a mobile devices, I found one (via stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3023446/2100636) that works with jQuery and ui theming. I am adding this one as an answer because it may be good to consider because it's rooted in the idea of **functionality**. It has options I didn't see with other pickers, and I think I can incorporate it into a responsive/mobile design pretty well. I'll update with my progress if I end up using it.

From their website, http://www.ama3.com/anytime/, the description below sums it up better than I can. It's also licensed under Creative Commons.

> For starters, take a look at these DATE/TIME ALTERNATIVES:

```
12-hour or 24-hour clock
custom date/time format (countless possibilities, including JSON and XML)
date-only, time-only, or specific fields!
date/time range limits
era-selection (BCE/CE, BC/AD, etc.)
start week on any day (Sunday, Monday, etc.)
custom base for 2-digit years (1900, 2000, etc.)
UTC offsets and time zones
```

> Then peep these STYLING CHOICES:

```
custom labels/languages
custom CSS styles
jQuery UI Theming
jQuery UI Theme Switcher
jQuery ThemeRoller
pop-up or always-present picker
visible or hidden field
```

> It's also PROGRAMMER-FRIENDLY:

```
easy to implement
easy AJAX validation
easy Date/String conversion, including JSON and XML
create multiple pickers at once
easy removal 
easy to extend
```

> And let's not forget those USABILITY FEATURES:

```
single-click value selection
double-click select-and-dismiss
WAI-ARIA 1.0 keyboard accessibility
em-based relative-size
```

Answer (score -1):

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/

The DateBox is very neat and works well for those still looking.

Comment: Redundant answer...it's the same as the accepted answer, and it was answered more than a year before this answer was given.