# jQuery mobile calendar with 3-state day colours

Tags: calendar, datepicker, jquery-mobile

I am looking at creating an event and reservation system.

I found the Stack Overflow question [jQuery - Mobile date picker control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549729) which shows [jquery-mobile-datebox](https://github.com/jtsage/jquery-mobile-datebox) and [jQuery-Mobile-Themed-DatePicker](https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Mobile-Themed-DatePicker).

I want to display a calendar where certain dates I get from the server are

1. available
2. not available
3. reserved

When a reserved or available date is touched, I want to show times - there can be more than one time per day. The user can then click on a time to reserve it which would hit off an Ajax request.

jQuery UI datepicker, for example, has

```
 onSelect: function(date, inst) {
```

From what I can see in the above pickers, what I need is not readily available. Before I start hacking them myself:

1. Which one would lend itself best to what I want?
2. Are there perhaps better ones out there that already serve my needs?

---

UPDATE:

Firebug gave me

`<div class="ui-datebox-griddate ui-corner-all ui-btn-up-e" data-date="25" data-theme="e">25</div>`

where ui-btn-up-e can be changed from a - e.

Now I need to find out if data-theme also needs to be changed

```
 $('.ui-datebox-griddate').click(function () {
   alert($(this).attr("class"));
 }
```

What is the nicest way to toggle through three of the classes and save the state each time?

```
 $('.ui-datebox-griddate').toggle(
   function () {
     $(this).????? // change ui-btn-up-? to ui-btn-up-a
     $.get(...)
  },
   function () {
     $(this).????? // change ui-btn-up-a to ui-btn-up-b
     $.get(...)
  },
   function () {
     $(this).????? // change ui-btn-up-b to ui-btn-up-c
     $.get(...)
  }
);
```

UPDATE: NOTE: When I click, the calendar change the date, reloading the calendar completely. Perhaps I need to stop that :(

Comment: fwiw, DateBox got a few updates today and yesterday, chief among them that it now allows highDates, an array of dates to highlight (e.q. you're "reserved"), it already had blackDates (e.q. "Not Available").  It does have some callback support, but you'd have to do some work to get the list of times functionality.

Comment: thanks for asking this question. i had the same question come up too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what J.T.Sage said I thought I would have a play with jQuery Mobile Calendar. I think I have something which could potentially be extended to fulfil your requirements.  I am not sure to what extent multi-colour themeing would be possible (without extensive modifications).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQueryMobile - DateBox Demos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- NOTE: Script load order is significant! -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){ $.mobile.page.prototype.options.degradeInputs.date = 'text'; });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#page').live('pagecreate', function(event) {
        $('#mydate').bind('change', function () {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page" data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "calHighToday": false, "calHighPicked": false, "useInline": true, "useInlineHideInput": true, "highDates": ["2011-06-25", "2011-06-27", "2011-07-04"]}'></input>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

I suppose the *highDates* mechanism could be bypassed completely and the individual days uniquely targeted.  The plugin maintains a JavaScript Date object of the last date selected (or today if nothing has been selected) - so it should be possible to get the current month and iterate through all your matching data updating the matching days in the current month as appropriate (e.g. replacing the *setColours* method below with something that is data/state aware).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#page').live('pagecreate', function(event) {

    $('#mydate').bind('change', function () {
        //alert($(this).val());
        alert($('#mydate').data('datebox').theDate);
    });
    setColours();

    $('#mydate').bind('datebox', function (e, pressed) {
        setColours();
    });

    $('.ui-datebox-gridplus, .ui-datebox-gridminus').bind('vclick', function(){
         // To handle changing months
          setColours();
         //alert($('#mydate').data('datebox').theDate);
    });

    function setColours(){
        $('div.ui-datebox-griddate[data-date=25][data-theme]').css({"background-color":"red", "background-image":"none", "color" : "white"});
        $('div.ui-datebox-griddate[data-date=26][data-theme]').css({"background-color":"green", "background-image":"none", "color" : "white"});
        $('div.ui-datebox-griddate[data-date=27][data-theme]').css({"background-color":"blue", "background-image":"none", "color" : "white"});
    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking, where does the toggle colour come in?

Comment: Aha. Firebug gave me `<div class="ui-datebox-griddate ui-corner-all ui-btn-up-e" data-date="25" data-theme="e">25</div>` where ui-btn-up-e can be changed from a - e. Now I need to find out if data-theme also needs to be changed

Comment: Yes, there are jQuery Mobile themes. http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/themes.html  You can specify which theme you want to use for highlighting (pickPageOHighButtonTheme) but I think this theme is then used for all highlighting.

Comment: Thanks - Please see my update. I do not think I need to care about the theme, however I have not tried to change a className inside multiple classes before...

Comment: fwiw, that data-theme is used for the hover function.  It pulls that for the up and down classes.

Comment: Thanks. @Mark or @JTS Can you figure out a way to do what I need to do? It looked very simple, but I think I need to intercept the click/change, save it and do some hocus pocus to change the colour of the button so it is picked up on the re-draw

Comment: This works on Firefox, Chrome and Safari - I just noticed that this does not work in IE8 (although I don't think IE8 is actually a mobile browser engine).

Comment: @Mark - I did not have time to look yet. but thanks for your input so far

Answer (score 5):

> What is the nicest way to toggle through three of the classes and save the state each time?

Something like:

```
$('.ui-datebox-griddate').click(function (e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var cycle = ["ui-btn-up-a", "ui-btn-up-b", "ui-btn-up-c"];

  if (typeof $this.data("ui-btn-cycle") == "undefined" ) {
    this.className = this.className.replace(/ui-btn-up-./, cycle[0]);
    $this.data("ui-btn-cycle", cycle[0]);
  }

  for (var i=0; i<cycle.length; i++) {
    if ( $this.hasClass(cycle[i]) ) {
      $this.removeClass(cycle[i]).addClass(cycle[i % cycle.length]);
      $this.data("ui-btn-cycle", [i % cycle.length]);
      break;
    }
  }
  $.get( ... );

  e.preventDefault() // stop default click behaviour
});
```

This can cycle though an arbitrary amount of classes. The current state would be available through calling `.data("ui-btn-cycle")` on the respective element.

This is even nicer:

```
$('.ui-datebox-griddate')
.each(function () {
  var cycle = ["ui-btn-up-a", "ui-btn-up-b", "ui-btn-up-c"];
  $(this).data("ui-btn-cycle", cycle);
  this.className = this.className.replace(/ui-btn-up-./, cycle[0]);
})
.click(function (e) {
  var cycle = $(this).data("ui-btn-cycle");
  $(this).removeClass(cycle[0]).addClass(cycle[1]);
  cycle.push(cycle.shift());
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

The current state would always be `.data("ui-btn-cycle")[0]` on the respective element. See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/mAH4n/

Comment: Great! - I have not had the time to check it, but it looks doable. Why not toggle(function, function, function) by the way ? You solution will be shorter since I need to do the ajax for each toggle but just wondering

Comment: @mplungjan Because [`toggle()` does not work this way](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: @Tomalak yes, the [other toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) does work that way :)

Comment: @mplungjan Oh, nice. :) Didn't even know that one. May be a useful alternative, just create a separate function for the Ajax call and your're good.

Comment: It was the one I posted in my update - I guess you just thought I created a fantasy method ;)

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, I was a bit unsure. ;) Anyway, see the alternative I added, maybe you like that one more than my original suggestion.

Comment: Yikes - that is write-only code :) So I put the $.get() before the preventDefault, still?

Comment: @mplungjan I find it quite clear (I compressed it a little bit to emphasize that it's shorter, feel free to add more format to it for readability). It does not matter where `.preventDefault()` is, it can be anywhere in the function. I put things like this last for convention, not for purpose. Corollary: Call `$.get()` where you feel like it. ;)

Comment: It is the $('.ui-datebox-griddate')
.data("ui-btn-cycle", cycle)
.each - I did not quite grasp. I never used .data before so I needed to read up on that

Comment: @mplungjan: data() just adds a named piece of data to every matched element. Note that there was a bug (I passed in a reference, which is the wrong thing to do) and it's *even* shorter now.

Comment: Happy to see it since I did not get the $this=$(this) either

Comment: @mplungjan That's just a regular JavaScript variable assignment, nothing exciting here.

Comment: Erm normally such assignments in jQuery will change the type of object

Comment: @mplungjan No they don't. ;-) `$` is a valid first character for a JavaScript variable name, so assigning the result of `$(this)` (a jQuery object) to the variable `$this` is pure convenience and nothing special. The value of `this` stays untouched.

Comment: I realise that, I could not see the point if nothing else happened

Comment: @mplungjan "Nothing else happend"? Well, I *use* the variable, of course. If I need to do `$(this)` more than one or two times in a function body, I usually have a `$this` variable around, see my first version of the answer. I'm not sure if we are just misunderstanding each other here?

Comment: No, I think I understood, but you only used it once so I was curious if there was a side effect (closure/conversion to non-jquery object) that I had missed